# Error generated when clicking on insert image in a CMS page

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, magento-1, image, error-log

While in a CMS page, when I click on "Insert image", it creates the following error.  This error is repeated for the number of images displayed in the popup window! If the pop up displays 6 images, the error is repeated 6 times in the `system.log`.

But clicking on the "Insert image", pointing to the same folder, the second or third time the error is not generated.

What is causing this?  How can I prevent this error from being generated?  Is this some how being cached?

Note: I have tried turning off all my third party extensions, but it produces the same errors.

```
2016-08-20T22:26:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] /home/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:52
[1] /home/magento/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:768
[2] /home/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:84
[3] /home/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:184
[4] /home/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:354
[5] /home/magento/app/Mage.php:684
[6] /home/magento/index.php:91
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the fact that headers are sent twice when your code is called. You probably have a module doing this as its not the default Magento behavior.

I suggest you have a look at the two answers from Alan Storm here to debug the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670031/magento-debug-headers-already-sent-error

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Trying @Alan Storm method 1, produced a log of 167 record long.  The second method modifying `Abstract.php` produced the following additional lines `2016-08-21T14:51:55+00:00 DEBUG (7): File: /home/magento/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php` and `2016-08-21T14:51:55+00:00 DEBUG (7): Line: 172` .  But I do not know how to debug this.  Any ideas?